# mysqli real escape string adds backslashes to DB entry?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysql-real-escape-string

I am trying to insert text, which contains apostrophes or quotes, into my DB. However, I tried using the mysqli real escape string function in order to escape the quotes, but now it adds backslashes to my inserts into the DB?

```
$description = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["description"]);
$sql = "UPDATE posts SET description='$description' WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1"; 
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die (mysqli_error());
```

So after saving, and re-opening the edit page to edit the post again, I end up with with tons of backslashes after saving multiple times, for example "company\\'s".

Comment: Check if you have Magic Quotes (google that) activated and/or are escaping again somewhere. You're simply escaping one time too many somewhere.

Comment: Magic Quotes are disabled apparently. However when I do not use the mysqli_real_escape_string then my syntax breaks due to the quote.